# Constructing a format string using variables

Tags: ruby, string, hash, string-formatting

String format works like this:

```
someString = "Example string %{key}"
result = someString % {key: newData}
```

I would like to retrieve the hash keys in the string without hardcoding them. Is there a method for doing this?

Also, is there any way to construct the format string using variables? I would like to do something like this:

```
variable = key 
result = someString % {variable: newData}
```

Comment: Second part of your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. Just a bit off with the syntax

```
variable = :key # get this one from whereever
someString = "Example string %{key}"
someString % { variable => 'foo' } # => "Example string foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to extract keys from the format string:

```
"Example string %{key1} %{key2}".scan /(?<=%{)[^{}]+?(?=})/
# => ["key1", "key2"]
```

The regex `(?<=%{)[^{}]+?(?=})` matches one or more characters (non-greedy) if it's prefixed by `%{` and followed by `}`.

---

To construct the format string, you can use string interpolation:

```
variable = 'key'
"Example string %{#{variable}}"
# => "Example string %{key}"
```

Comment: `\w` is too pessimistic. There should be `[^{}]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa You are right, updated. Although I doubt non-words keys are used in practice, like `'%{hello there}' % {:"hello there" => 45}`

Comment: I bet they are in i18n. At least, they could be.

Comment: It's a bit more complex. Named references can also be enclosed in angle brackets (`%<key>s`) and you have to take `%%` into account.